# How to use this json and show it in browser?

Tags: javascript, web-services, json, api

I frequently use this [twitter api website](http://www.tweetscan.com/api.php) to search. It provides its own api. Now I want to try it but do not know how to do it. My idea is:

1. Put a search box in html and in `onclick` event it will retrieve json
2. Parse that json and count the length of each tweet (only length of tweet text, not userid)
3. Display each tweet userid, date, link, text (all tweet data) in browser
4. Length of tweet text is appending to (3) for each tweet

I am new in javascript and json. Will you let me know how to retrieve json and do above?

Comment: Learn the basics about JavaScript first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide , especially about objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, it would help to review the [fundamentals of JSON requests](http://json.org/JSONRequest.html).  Once you do that, feel free to brush up on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to retrieve the JSON you want from a given URL.  Here's some pseudo code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://tweetscan.com/json.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 's' : 'some search phrase' },
  success: function (response) {
    // Do something with JSON response.
  }
});
```

Comment: Again, not a functional example.